# How to add shadow to the panel?

Tags: unity, 11.04, panel

Will this feature be enabled in Natty (with unity panel)?

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug that has been fixed. See the [developer's blog](http://codearmada.com/2011/03/31/the-return-of-the-panel-shadow/) for information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this feature is enabled in Natty. You can configure this option with Compiz. Open it

```
ccsm
```

Go to **Window Decoration** and change it as you like.

Comment: I mean in unity